# Is there a better way to install Ubuntu 21.10 Lite Desktop?

Tags: system-installation, desktop-environments, 21.10

The method it uses now is to install the Full Ubuntu 21.10 desktop, then remove all the flotsam & jetsam. It took me ~ 20 minutes to install 21.10 server, but over 2 hours to install the 'Lite' desktop.
If recommendations are taken, how about:

1. 3 images / isos? Server, Lite, and Full, like Raspberry Pi Foundation
2. 2 images / isos, but make Desktop like Server. Select packages you want to install.
3. Like () M$, Multiple versions in the ISO like their WIM...
   My boss is now having me look at modding the scripting we use for 'install' to use on a different distro, as this took entirely too long...

Comment: The Ubuntu Developers have repeatedly said that they are not interested in supporting any "lite" or "minimal" ideas. If a community member wants to publish a minimal respin, they certainly can --it's all open source-- but they might not be permitted to use the "Ubuntu" name with a different experience.  It took me about 40 minutes to download the .iso, create the installer, reboot, and install Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop yesterday, so your "over 2 hours" is not universal.

Comment: There are many "lite" install methods already for fleets: dd-able .img files, PXE boot, Ubuntu Base, and others. None are as simple and straightforward as the Desktop .iso, but many can be used to speed up or customize fleet installs. The Dekstop installer also has a "Minimal" option: It lacks the lotsam and jetsam, but is no swifter than the full install. It's unclear if your priority is the packages you don't use or if your priority is the install time.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.